# Drools 5 with Java/JDK 11

Tags: java, drools, java-11

Has anyone tried running Drools 5.x with Java/JDK 11? There is huge gap in the release dates of the two, so seems less likely to be compatible.

If you have tried, it would be great if you share your experience.

Thanks!

Comment: not really the type of question to be asked here, maybe reach out to the drool bug tracker or email to drools-usage@googlegroups.com.

Comment: Do you mean, compile an app that has a Drools 5 dependency with JDK 11 ... or do you mean use Java 11 language features in your DRLs?

Comment: Because I did manage to get a Drools 5 app running in Java 9 (not quite 11 though; that hadn't been released yet), but not language features in the DRLs. That being said, I didn't actually have to do anything to get the JDK 9 app working -- it just did out of the box. (Caveat: it only worked if i was using mvel dialect; java dialect caused compilation errors in the rules.)